# fix duplicate columns names in csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

Given a comma separated plain text file import-week10.csv file, I'd like to change the header, to fix a duplicate column name issue. The "corrected" header would be available in another file correct.csv (the only row there). File import-week10.csv would then be saved (overwritten) with this new header.

Example first row in the file:

```
ID,name,surname,DOB,name,surname,DOB,amount
```

or

```
ID,"name","surname","DOB",name,surname,DOB,amount
```

should become, with unique column names:

```
ID,"name main","surname main","DOB main","name joint","surname joint","DOB joint",amount
```

First question, how do I script this change with Powershell ?

Second question, I would like to compare and get a warning: if this first row has changed in import-week10.csv, from last week's file import-week09.csv. Assuming new columns will be added, or changed, every couple weeks.

Environment: WS 2012 R2, could update to latest PS version if need be.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Comment: Get-Content "import-week10.csv" | select -First 2 | Out-File "test.csv"

    Import-CSV -Header ID,"name main","surname main","DOB main","name joint","surname joint","DOB joint",amount test.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to your literal question but I'm not positive it is really what you want:

```
$correctHeader = (Get-Content .\correct.csv)[0]
$in = Get-Content  .\import-week10.csv
$in[0] = $correctHeader
$in | Set-Content .\correct.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I need. I have the correct row with the column names in correct.csv, and I would like to use it to replace the row in import-week10.csv, and save the updated version.

Comment: For some reason this gets only the first char from the header, not the whole line as required.

Comment: Really? That is super odd. This code works for me. How exactly are you implementing it?

Comment: As you've written it in the answer. But it works ok for me like this: $correctHeader = Get-Content .\correct.csv | Select-Object -First 1